# Leo's passive skill

Tags: summoners-war

Today I got a Leo, but haven't had the opportunity to deal with him very often.
His 3rd skill (passive) lacks description, so I have a few questions about it.

> Eye of the Storm (Passive)
>   The attack speed of all enemies and allies
>   is limited to your attack speed.  (...)

What happens if you buff your own team with Speed (e.g. using Bernard) and Leo (on Violent Runes) used up his charges before the rest of my team?

**Does everyone fall back to Leo's now lower Speed instantly or on his next turn?**

Example:

[image]

Also, if Leo dies the skill will no longer affect anyone and all monsters will regain their original Speed (if higher than Leo's). But since it's a passive skill, can you disable it (unlike Theomars' Elemental King, which can be put on cool down) with skills other than Tesarion's passive, which explicitly does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With his passive, the speed of **all** monsters, both enemies and allies, is capped at Leo's speed value and leo moves first.

For example if all monsters have 200 total speed and leo has 120 speed, then all monster will have 120 speed, but Leo will move first. The speed of all monsters **immediately** change.

And no, there is no way to, in my knowledge, turn off a passive skill.

Comment: Does this also count for getting and losing speed buffs? That's what the question primarily is about. I know the effect of Leo's passive, but I want to know if it's instantly updated if Leo's speed changes during the fight (e.g. getting or losing a speed buff).

Comment: Yes if his speed changes the rest will immediately change to match